# How do I know when a control can be focused?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have my own Treeview control derived from `TCustomTreeView`.

I have added some of my own procedures to the class such as adding nodes. When this procedure is called at runtime I wanted the newly added node to be selected and for the Treeview to be focused so the new node is highlighted.

Here is a extract:

```
procedure TMyTreeView.AddGroup(AName: string);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Obj: TGroup;

  procedure AddToTree;
  begin
    Obj := TGroup.Create(AName);
    FGroups.Add(Obj);

    Node := Items.AddObject(Node, AName, Obj);
    with Node do
    begin
      ImageIndex := 0;
      SelectedIndex := 0;
    end;

    Selected := Node;
    SetFocus;
  end;

begin
  Node := nil;
  AddToTree;
end;
```

The above works but I am facing the common error message when calling from the Forms `OnCreate` event:

> Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window

I know you can use the `OnActivate` event or just don't use `OnCreate` at all which will not result in the error, but anyone else who may use the component may not realise this.

So I wanted to know if there is a way to determine if my Treeview (or any control) is able to receive the focus, then I could add a little checking of my own, something like:

```
if ControlIsFocusable then
begin
  Selected := Node;
  SetFocus;
end;
```

I know there is the `Loaded` procedure you can override which tells us when the control is loaded but then that would only work on first run. If the control became hidden by the user at runtime (or was not visible to begin with) the `Cannot focus a disabled or invisible window` error is still going to show up.

The dirty way to do it when not run in the debugger is:

```
try
  Selected := Node;
  SetFocus;
except
end;
```

But that defeats the purpose and I hate handling errors in this way.

So basically I wanted to know if there was a way to determine if a control can receive focus, so that we can set the focus to it?

Comment: I think you are doing this wrong. The control should not call `SetFocus` on itself. I can imagine no scenario where that is the correct behaviour. The form or application or framework should determine focus. Not the control. Imagine what happens when you have a form with two such controls?

Comment: if  MyTreeView1.HandleAllocated and IsWindowVisible(MyTreeView1.Handle) then

Comment: You need CanFocus http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CanFocus

Comment: @Keith - That's not the case.

Comment: @Sertac - I missed the OnCreate bit

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not consider if there were 2 or more instances of the control, I was testing with just one. Sounds like I am setting myself up for a few headaches doing this.

Comment: I'm as certain as I can be that a control calling `Self.SetFocus` is just wrong.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz How about a health warning to go with that?

Comment: @David - I have a vote on the comment preceding mine. I suppose it's enough for a warning.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz that would be my vote ironically :) Maybe I should understand what the warnings are before I voted it.

Comment: @Blobby - I meant my vote on David's comment. ;) Thanks for yours. :) I can't think of anything other than to consider than what's in David's comment.

Comment: Anyway, let me restate it: It doesn't matter if there are one or more controls are used, the problem is not just technical. As a component writer you're not in discretion of deciding what control will have focus when a form is shown or when a node is added etc., it's the component's user's decision.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz well thanks for writing the little snippet above, `IsWindowVisible` is new to me so I now know at least one more thing. And having read yours and David's comments I understand its plain wrong so I am best just deleting the `SetFocus` line all together.

Comment: @Blobby - You're welcome. `IsWindowVisible` reflects the actual visibility of the api level window of a control, rather than an *intention* which VCL's `visible` states. You can have a `visible` control in a hidden parent for instance, which you can't see of course. That's about the same for `CanFocus` which Keith mentioned, it won't help while the form itself is `visible`, but is not *actually* visible (that's the case in `OnCreate`). `Showing` is more in synch with actual visibility, but asking the api is the safest choice if what you're interested is what the api thinks about visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to answer the question that you asked, because I think you are doing this wrong.

The control should not call `SetFocus` on itself. I can imagine no scenario where that is the correct behaviour. The form or application or framework should determine focus. Not the control.

Imagine what happens when you have a form with two such controls? Imagine using the keyboard to focus a button, which you then press with the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> bar. If the action attached to the button calls your control's method which then changes the focus, you've just gone against the platform UI guidelines. You control now places a severe burden on any application that attempts to consume it.

Comment: Ok I now realise this is a mistake. As I commented before I was testing with just one instance of my control and so the scenario of having multiple controls never came to mind. Now that you have brought this to my attention I can see what I am trying to do is wrong and bad. So I agree about not answeing the question I asked because it is basically invalid now and would only be trying to solve a problem that should not exist in the first place. So with that been said, the solution is to just remove the `SetFocus` line, if a user needs the node to be highlighted they can set focus themselves.

Comment: It is also worth noting about the `HideSelection` property, setting to False at least indicates what current node is selected.